# Shopware 6 plugin: How to configure quick search options

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6, quick-search

I'm developing a Shopware 6 plugin where I need to make the search quick search component configurable, allowing the user to set options like:

- Whether to show country select
- Default search country
- Show detailed link in pins

In my plugin I have a configuration with elements like:

```xml
<config>
  <elements>
    <select>
      <name>showCountrySelect</name>
      <options>
        <option value="true">Yes</option>
        <option value="false">No</option>
      </options>
    </select>

    <select>
      <name>defaultSearchCountry</name>
      <options>
        <option value="de">Germany</option>
        <option value="us">United States</option>
        <!-- other country options -->
      </options>
    </select>

    <select>
      <name>showDetailedLink</name>
      <options>
        <option value="true">Yes</option>
        <option value="false">No</option>
      </options>
    </select>
  </elements>
</config>
```

And in my subscriber I'm reading those configuration values:

```php
// read config values
$showCountrySelect = $config->get('showCountrySelect');
```

Now in my plugin I want to conditionally show/hide parts of the default storefront quick search component template based on those config values.

```html
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/listing/filter/filter-panel.html.twig' %}

{% block component_quick_search_form %}
  {{ parent() }}

  {% if showCountrySelect %}
 {{ countrySelect }}
  {% endif %}
  
{% endblock %}
```

But this does not seem to override the block properly.

Comment: Are you using `showCountrySelect` like that or you set it as a variable somewhere?
After defining it in your config.xml, you have to use `config()` method in your twig file like that: `{{ config('YourPlugin.config.showCountrySelect') }}` (or set it into a variable `{% set myVariable = config('YourPlugin.config.showCountrySelect') %}`)